# The file "/Users/username/Documents/workspace/LifeExp/bin/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv" is missing or inaccessible

Tags: java, processing

I'm looking into UC San Diego's OOP course on coursera. I have to take a CVS file, then process it and parse the date into a hashmap for the second assignment they had given. But when I try to load the CSV file it seems that Java can't get an access to it.

```
package app;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google.GoogleMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class LifeExpectancy extends PApplet {

    //properties
    UnfoldingMap map;
    GoogleMapProvider provider; 
    File csvFile;

    //setup method
    //it only runs once, so write your code accordingly
    public void setup() {
        csvFile = new File("/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv");
        try {
            loadLifeExpectancyfromCSV(csvFile.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        size(800, 600, OPENGL);
        provider = new GoogleMapProvider();
        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 700, 500, provider);
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);


        }

    //draw method
    //it is dynamic, that means it runs through the program's runtime
    //so write your code accordingly
    public void draw() {
        map.draw();
    }

    //methods

    /**
     * Loads a CSV file, parses it and returns the parsed data accordingly
     * @param fileName name of the file that will be loaded
     * @return parsed data that comes from the file
     */
    private Map<String, Float> loadLifeExpectancyfromCSV(String fileName) {
        Map<String, Float> lifeExpMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();

        String[] rows = loadStrings(fileName);

        for (String row : rows) {
            String[] columns = row.split(",");
            float value = Float.parseFloat(columns[5]);
            lifeExpMap.put(columns[4], value);
        }

        return lifeExpMap;
    }
}
```

When I run this code this happens:

```
The file "/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.LifeExpectancy.loadLifeExpectancyfromCSV(LifeExpectancy.java:59)
    at app.LifeExpectancy.setup(LifeExpectancy.java:27)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, someone has to say it. You are missing the file "/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv"

Comment: nope, i already added it

Comment: So if you open a terminal and run "ls /data" (you're on unix, I assume?) you'd see that file? Notice that is the root path of your filesystem, not the current directory running your code

Comment: Try changing `new File("/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv");` to `new File("data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv");` without the leading `/`.

Comment: If the path to your file is not located within the classpath then make sure you supply the exact full path to the file, for example in Windows: "C:/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv". You should also apply a file check to your code to make sure the file actually exists before processing it by using something like:  if (!csvFile.exists()) { System.out.println("\u001B[31m" + "FILE NOT FOUND!" + "\u001B[39;49m"); return; }